# Commutative inner inverse for non-unital strongly regular ring

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-rings

An element $a$ in a ring $R$ is called **strongly regular** if $a \in a^2R$ and $a \in Ra^2$, in other words $a = a^2x$ and $a = ya^2$ for some elements $x,y \in R$. Say that $R$ is a unital ring. $a \in R$ is a strongly regular element if and only if a single element $b$ can be chosen for $a$ such that $a = a^2b$, $a = ba^2$, and $ab = ba$. The proof that I've seen for this depends on the fact that $R \cong \text{End}_R(_RR)$ which only holds if $R$ is a unital ring.

Is there a similar characterization or elementwise proof for this in the case where $R$ is a non-unital ring?

Comment: Do you know whether the characterisation you mention also holds in the non-unital case?

Comment: I do not know, but I don't have any reason to believe that it does not hold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a short proof in the general (non-unital) case.

We have
$$
(1) \qquad a^2x=a.
$$
$$
(2)\qquad ya^2=a.
$$
If we reduce the monomial $ya^2x$ using (1), we get $ya$, but if we use (2) we get $ax$.  Thus
$$
(3) \qquad ya=ax.
$$
Combining (3) and (2) we get
$$
(4) \qquad axa=a.
$$
I claim that $b:=yax$ satisfies the condition you seek.  Indeed, we compute
$$
ab=ayax=a^2x^2=ax
$$
(where we used (3) for the second equality and (1) for the last equality).  On the other hand
$$
ba=yaxa=ya=ax
$$
(where the used (4) for the second equality and (3) for the last equality).  Thus $ab=ba$.  Finally, $aba=axa=a$.

Comment: By the way, the answer to LSpice's question is yes, the given criterion is the standard definition of strongly regular elements even for non-unital rings.